# JSON.Net BSON serialization incorrectly handling DateTimeOffset?

Tags: json.net, bson

I'm trying to use JSON.Net to serialize to BSON, but the original offset does not appear to be respected.

Can you see a problem how I'm trying to make this work?

```
[Test]
public void SerializeDateTimeOffsetToBson()
{
    var serializer = new Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer {
        TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Auto,
        DateParseHandling = DateParseHandling.DateTimeOffset,
        DateTimeZoneHandling = DateTimeZoneHandling.RoundtripKind
    };

    var negOffset = new DateTimeOffset(2014, 7, 10, 0, 0, 0, new TimeSpan(-5, 0, 0));
    var gmtOffset = new DateTimeOffset(2014, 7, 10, 0, 0, 0, new TimeSpan());
    var posOffset = new DateTimeOffset(2014, 7, 10, 0, 0, 0, new TimeSpan(5, 0, 0));

    var dt = new {
        negOffset = negOffset,
        gmtOffset = gmtOffset,
        posOffset = posOffset
    };

    byte[] serialized;

    using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
    using (var writer = new BsonWriter(ms)) {
        serializer.Serialize(writer, dt);
        writer.Close();
        serialized = ms.ToArray();
    }

    dynamic deserializedDt;

    using (var ms = new MemoryStream(serialized))
    using (var rdr = new BsonReader(ms)) {
        deserializedDt = (dynamic)serializer.Deserialize(rdr);
        rdr.Close();
    }

    Assert.IsTrue(deserializedDt.negOffset == dt.negOffset);
    Assert.IsTrue(deserializedDt.posOffset == dt.posOffset);
    Assert.IsTrue(deserializedDt.gmtOffset == dt.gmtOffset);
}
```

All three of the assertions will fail.

After deserialization, `deserializedDt.negOffset` is July 9th 2014 10 PM with an offset of -07:00 (computer's current time zone), `deserializedDt.posOffset`  is July 9th 2014 12 PM with an offset of -07:00, and `deserializedDt.gmtOffset` is July 9th 2014 5 PM with an offset of -07:00.

Using JSON.Net 8.0.3 in a .Net 4.0 project.

UPDATE------------------

After further investigation, I've opened an issue about this on Github at https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/issues/898

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a second solution I came to after my previous answer that I ended up settling on.

The advantage of this one is you don't have to decorate each and every instance of DateTimeOffset or DateTimeOffset?, and it will also work on framework classes that you don't control and can't decorate (such as Tuples).  It just works, without any additional effort.

Converter is modified to save as a string instead of splitting into an object:

```
public class DateTimeOffsetConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return typeof(DateTimeOffset) == objectType
            || typeof(DateTimeOffset?) == objectType;
    }

    public override object ReadJson(
        JsonReader reader, 
        Type objectType, 
        object existingValue, 
        Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (reader.TokenType != JsonToken.String && reader.TokenType != JsonToken.Date)
            return null;

        DateTimeOffset dt;

        // If you need to deserialize already-serialized DateTimeOffsets,
        // it would come in as JsonToken.Date, uncomment to handle. Newly 
        // serialized values will come in as JsonToken.String.
        //if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.Date)
        //  return (DateTimeOffset)reader.Value;

        var dateWithOffset = (String)reader.Value;

        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(dateWithOffset))
            return null;

        if (DateTimeOffset.TryParseExact(dateWithOffset, "O", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.RoundtripKind, out dt))
            return dt;

        return null;
    }

    public override void WriteJson(
        JsonWriter writer, 
        object value, 
        Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var dateTimeOffset = (DateTimeOffset)value;

        // Serialize DateTimeOffset as round-trip formatted string
        serializer.Serialize(writer, dateTimeOffset.ToString("O"));
    }
}
```

Need a custom ContractResolver to inject the converter when required:

```
public class DateTimeOffsetContractResolver: DefaultContractResolver
{
    protected override JsonContract CreateContract(Type objectType)
    {
        var contract = base.CreateContract(objectType);

        if (objectType == typeof(DateTimeOffset) || objectType == typeof(DateTimeOffset?) 
            contract.Converter = new DateTimeOffsetConverter();

        return contract;
    }
}
```

And configure JSON.Net to use your ContractResolver:

```
var serializer = new JsonSerializer {
    ContractResolver = new DateTimeOffsetContractResolver()
};
```

Comment: Same thing as with JSON repeating with BSON, when will they learn: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/OnTheNightmareThatIsJSONDatesPlusJSONNETAndASPNETWebAPI.aspx

Answer (score 2):

The BSON spec doesn't allow for storing a DateTime's offset; [it stores UTC datetime as an Int64](http://bsonspec.org/spec.html), milliseconds since the Unix epoch.

If you don't want to lose the offset, you can create a JsonConverter that will separate the DateTime from the Offset to serialize (and deserialize) both separately. For example:

```
public class DateTimeOffsetConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return typeof(DateTimeOffset) == objectType;
    }

    public override object ReadJson(
        JsonReader reader, 
        Type objectType, 
        object existingValue, 
        Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (reader.TokenType != JsonToken.StartObject)
            return null;

        reader.Read(); // PropertyName "DateTimeInTicks"
        reader.Read(); // Property value
        var ticks = (Int64)reader.Value;

        reader.Read(); // PropertyName "Offset"
        reader.Read(); // Property value
        var offset = TimeSpan.Parse((String)reader.Value);

        // Move forward to JsonToken.EndObject
        reader.Read();

        return new DateTimeOffset(ticks, offset);
    }

    public override void WriteJson(
        JsonWriter writer, 
        object value, 
        Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var dateTimeOffset = (DateTimeOffset)value;

        var toSerialize = new {
            DateTimeInTicks = dateTimeOffset.DateTime.Ticks,
            Offset = dateTimeOffset.Offset
        };

        serializer.Serialize(writer, toSerialize);
    }
}
```

You can then apply it to your classes as follows:

```
public class TestClass
{
    public Int32 TestInt { get; set; }

    [JsonConverter(typeof(DateTimeOffsetConverter))] 
    public DateTimeOffset TestDateTimeOffset { get; set; }

    public String TestString { get; set; }

    [JsonConverter(typeof(DateTimeOffsetConverter))] 
    public DateTimeOffset? TestNullableDateTimeOffset { get; set; }
}
```